# Removing the gap between a firefox toolbarbutton and the dropdown marker

Tags: css, firefox, button, xul, toolbar

I have a `toolbarbutton` of type `menu-button` which is working perfectly in my Firefox extension, however it's not styled quiet as I'd like.

There is a gap with an outline between the buttpon image and the dropdown marker arrow (the red arrow shows the outlined gap I'm referring to - the outline is part of the problem - and you can also see the AdBlock Plus button which does not have this problem).

[image: Red arrow shows the outlined gap]

Also, when you hover over the image/button a shaded grey background appears.

[image: showing the shaded grey background on hovering over the button]

I'd like to remove the gap (AdBlock Plus manages this with their toolbar button  but I haven't figured out how) and also remove the shading (I hava hover image defined for the button which should be sufficient to indicate that you are in the click-zone).

Can anyone give me any pointers? It seems to be something to do with the following two classes: `toolbarbutton-1` and `chromeclass-toolbar-additional`

Thanks,

FM

Comment: I've now discovered that the gap disappears when I have 'small icons' selected in the toolbar customise screen. Maybe this holds a clue, but even trawling through the DOM inspector comparing CSS I can't find what's causing the gap.

Answer (score 0):

The gap is because the type is "menu-button", and ADP button type is "menu". The gap style is depend on the theme you are using.

The image problem, how do you setup the image? In my case, it work fine to setup with

```
button.style.listStyleImage =  'url("chrome://referrercontrol/skin/icon24.png");'
```

Comment: Aha! You're absolutely right.. no 'click' action on the AB+ button, just the menu - that makes sense.

Comment: Regarding the image problem... I use the following to assign the same png to use for all icons:

`#BabelSheepButton
  {list-style-image: url("chrome://babelsheepbutton/content/babelSheepButton.png");}`

then the following to pull out the correct region for the normal and hover modes

`.babelsheepbutton                  
  {-moz-image-region: rect( 0px 28px 25px  0px);}

.babelsheepbutton:hover     
  {-moz-image-region: rect( 0px 56px 25px  28px);}`

The hover image is shown when I hover, but also that gradient background which I don't want.

Comment: Maybe Firefox default css cause it, or you can try add `!important`.