# Changing Pale Moon :hover menu-button transparency with CSS

Tags: css, firefox, hover, icons, transparency

How do I change the button transparency when hovering over toolbarbutton / menu-button icons placed by extensions into the navigation toolbar area of Pale Moon? For example, there are three icons (HTTPS Everywhere, Adblock Plus, Greasemonkey) on the right side of the navigation bar.

Without hovering over the icons, this is how it looks in PM:

[image: Pale Moon non-hovered]

Then when hovering over the HTTPS Everywhere icon, I see this in PM:

[image: Pale Moon hovered]

In Firefox, I see this when hovering over the same icon:

[image: Firefox hovered]

I like the way it looks when hovering in Firefox, and would like to see the same in Pale Moon. It seems gentler without such a heavy contrast.

I am using Stylish to add custom CSS code to modify the icon backgrounds in PM. I tried the following CSS code:

> toolbarbutton:hover { background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0) !important; }

And when hovering over the same icon in PM, this yielded:

[image: Pale Moon hovered #2]

I wasn't happy to see the outside border. All I want to do is change the button to a lighter transparency, so I changed (255,255,255,1.0) to (255,255,255,0.3) and got this in PM:

[image: Pale Moon hovered #3]

It looked like both the button and the outside border were getting more transparent at the same time. I thought maybe setting RGBA to (255,255,255,0) would make the button look more like it does in Firefox when hovering, but no it remains exactly like the 2nd image shown in this post. Back to square one.

All I want is to modify the button's transparency without involving the outside border, and am not sure how to do that. That is where I need your help.

I saw two questions here at Stack Overflow that seemed closely related, but still couldn't fix the issue. Those two questions are:

- [Removing the gap between a firefox toolbarbutton and the dropdown marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816857/removing-the-gap-between-a-firefox-toolbarbutton-and-the-dropdown-marker)
- [Changing a button color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover)

The first link has pictures and they're pretty similar to what I show here. However, there's only one answer there and it doesn't seem to address what I need to know. Other CSS lines I tried were:

> toolbarbutton.button:hover{ background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0) !important; }

,

> toolbarbutton.button toolbarbutton:hover{ background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0) !important; }

,

> #toolbar-menubar:hover{ background-color: #414141 !important; }

But none of them had any effect in Pale Moon.

So how do I change the button's transparency (upon hovering) to be just like the one in Firefox without the outside border?

Comment: Instead of a transparent solid color, it looks like a transparent gradient. Perhaps the background may be applied to the actual a link or image, instead of its container? For the gradient, try something like (to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); for a white to transparent fade. Here's a gradient generator that has the transparency option. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Talkingrock I think you have a great suggestion there about looking into the link or image property instead of the container. I'll see if I can figure out what to do with it. Thanks for the link to the gradient generator!